# Vertical alignment within cells with increased height no longer working

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, height

The below code used to deliver me a nicely formated table having cells with an increased height and vertically centered text.  However, when rebuilding the the document now, the text is not vertically centered.  Any suggestions on how I could solve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{@{}m{0pt}@{}}

\begin{document}

\Large
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|M{3.5cm}|M{.7cm}|M{.7cm}|M{.7cm}|N}
 \hline
    \textbf{A}: & 1 & 2 & 3 & \\ [30pt] \hline
    \textbf{B}: & X & Y & Z & \\ [30pt] \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Table generated by code which you provide newer have vertical centered  content.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in comment, this table due to way how has terminated rows (`\\[20pt]`), newer has vertical centered contents of cells. If you like to have more vertical space in cells, then this you can achieve on many ways. One of them is use `cellspace` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{12pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{12pt}
\begin{tabular}{|O{M{3.5cm}}|O{M{.7cm}}|O{M{.7cm}}|O{M{.7cm}}|}
 \hline
    \textbf{A}: & 1 & 2 & 3     \\ \hline
    \textbf{B}: & X & Y & Z     \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]